# Python - split a string to multiple json string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to split a string and get all json string that are in it
My string :

> {"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 55, 223]}}}{"datas": {"type": "auth", "value": 0}}{"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 60, 218]}}}{"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 65, 213]}}}{"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 70, 208]}}}

My regex :

```
({.*})({.*)
```

But, the first group is the entire string without the last json string

> {"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 55, 223]}}}{"datas": {"type": "auth", "value": 0}}{"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 60, 218]}}}{"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 65, 213]}}}

I want to get one by one like this :

> {"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 55, 223]}}}

I don't know how to properly explain my problem, i hope you'll understand
Thanks for reading

---

**EDIT**: Finally, i didn't used regex.  
Here is my function :

```
def packet_to_jsonlist(s):
    jsonlist = []
    count = 0
    current = 0
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        if s[i] == '{':
            count += 1
        elif s[i] == '}':
            count -= 1
            if count == 0:
                jsonlist.append(s[current:i+1])
                current = i + 1

    return jsonlist
```

Comment: Don't try and process JSON strings. Parse it to a `dict` using `json.loads(...)` and use normal dict/list operations.

Comment: @Selcuk it's not a single dict.

Comment: ...or I should say, not a single json string.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Oh, right. The formatting does not make it obvious. I guess the best way is to fix the source if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a great *general* solution, but in this case you can split the individual strings on a regex matching the closing `}` next to the opening `{`. This will give you a list of json strings which you can then parse:

```
import re
import json

s = '{"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 55, 223]}}}{"datas": {"type": "auth", "value": 0}}{"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 60, 218]}}}{"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 65, 213]}}}{"datas": {"type": "custom", "value": {"cat": "game", "func": "game", "args": ["action", "move", "ball", 0, 70, 208]}}}'

js = re.split(r'(?<=})\B(?={)', s)

dicts = [json.loads(s) for s in js]
```

Making `dicts`:

```
[{'datas': {'type': 'custom',
   'value': {'cat': 'game',
    'func': 'game',
    'args': ['action', 'move', 'ball', 0, 55, 223]}}},
 {'datas': {'type': 'auth', 'value': 0}},
 {'datas': {'type': 'custom',
   'value': {'cat': 'game',
    'func': 'game',
    'args': ['action', 'move', 'ball', 0, 60, 218]}}},
 {'datas': {'type': 'custom',
   'value': {'cat': 'game',
    'func': 'game',
    'args': ['action', 'move', 'ball', 0, 65, 213]}}},
 {'datas': {'type': 'custom',
   'value': {'cat': 'game',
    'func': 'game',
    'args': ['action', 'move', 'ball', 0, 70, 208]}}}]
```

For a more general solution, you can make a quick parser that keeps track of balanced brackets and yields your strings:

```
def getGroups(s):
    current = ''
    count = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == '{':
            count += 1
        elif c == '}':
            count -=1 
        current += c
        if count == 0:
            yield current
            current = ''

[json.loads(js) for js in getGroups(s)]
# same output
```

This assumes the braces are balanced properly.

Comment: Finally, i didn't use regular expressions as you told me. Thanks!